# How can i write all the possibilities of the number $S$ as being a product of only two numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If i have  a number  $S = A×B×C$   where  $A , B , C$ are not necessarily primes ,  How can i write all the possibilities of  the number  $S$ as  being  a product of only two numbers ?

I need a general  method that i can follow.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Note that you want to count the number of divisors of $S$.

Comment: @PenasRaul  how did you deduce that?  Please elaborate more please

Comment: Consider the bijection $\{ d \text{ is a divisor of } S \} \to \{ (x, y) | xy = S \}$  given by $f(d) = (d, S/d)$.

Comment: If you are interested in counting $ \{ \{x, y\} | xy = S \}$, i.e. factorizations up to order, then it's half the number of divisors (rounded up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $S$ as $p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots p_m^{n_m}$ where $p_i$ are prime numbers. Now, the possible pair of numbers $(X,Y)$ such that $S = X \times Y$ is equal to the number of ways we can form $X$ which equals $N = \prod_{i=1}^{m}(n_i+1)$.

**Edit**: Based on the answer by Raffaele I realized that the order of the two numbers does not matter therefore the final answer must exclude double counting and hence, it will be $\frac{N}{2}$ if $N$ is even and $\frac{N+1}{2}$ if $N$ is odd.

In case when $N$ is odd $\implies$ all $n_i$'s are even, the pairs include $(X,X)$ where $X = p_1^{n_1/2}p_2^{n_2/2}\ldots p_m^{n_m/2}$ which is not double counted.

As an example, for $S = 2^23^2$, the possible pairs of $(X,Y)$ will be $\{(1,36),(2,18),(4,9),(3,12),(6,6),(12,3),(9,4),(18,2),(36,1)\}$, where $(6,6)$ will be the pair which will not be double counted.

Comment: Thank you @expiTTpz0    ,  can you demonstrate  you idea  on this example  : $S= 4×8×36$  , what is the number  and how can I  list them all?

Comment: $S = 2^73^2$. The number of possible pairs $(X,Y)$ equals $8\times 3=24$. Following will be the values of $X$ in those $24$ pairs - $2^k3^0 = \{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128\}, 2^k3^1 = \{3,6,12,24,48,96,192,384\}, 2^k3^2 = \{\text{8 distinct numbers different from the first two sets}\}$. The value of $Y$ corresponding to an $X$ will be $\frac{S}{X}$

Comment: brilliant  explanation  , thank you from heart

Answer (score 1):

$S=4\times 8\times 36=1152=2^7\cdot3^2$

Divisors of S are $(7+1)\cdot (2+1)=24$ the product of (exponents+1)

The divisors are
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 32, 36, 48, 64, 72, 96, 128,
144, 192, 288, 384, 576, 1152$$

If you multiply the first for the last, the second for the one before the last and so on you get 12 possibilities:
$  36\times 32,\; 48\times 24,\; 64\times 18,\; 72\times 
  16,\; 96\times 12,\; 128\times 9,\; 144\times 8,\;
  192\times 6,\; 288\times 4,\;384\times 3,\; 576\times 
  2,\;1152\times 1$

I hope I've been clear

Comment: thank very much  for your help  , you really clear it completely